# Decode Chess Move

Tags: code-golf, chess

As the title says, given a valid chess move in algebraic notation, produce the string describing the move.

**Example:**

```
fxg8=Q+  -> Pawn takes g8 promotes to Queen check
Bb7#     -> Bishop to b7 mate
```

Here is a list of all the keywords and their respective notation

```
R     -> Rook             x   -> takes
N     -> Knight           +   -> check
B     -> Bishop           #   -> mate
Q     -> Queen            =   -> promotes to
K     -> King             0-0 -> short castle
0-0-0 -> long castle
```

---

*Note: Long and short castle can be represented with either number `0` or letter `O` uppercase. You can choose any you'd like.*

***From wiki:** Both algebraic notation and descriptive notation indicate kingside castling as 0-0 and queenside castling as 0-0-0 (using the digit zero). Portable Game Notation and some publications use O-O for kingside castling and O-O-O for queenside castling (using the letter O) instead*

---

Piece moves format follows `{Piece name} to {square}` Moves without a piece are consider pawn moves. Example:

```
g4  -> Pawn to g4
Nh7 -> Knight to h7
```

For ambiguous moves, input will specify both departure rank and file. Example:

```
Rh8b8 -> Rook h8 to b8
Qb3e6 -> Queen b3 to e6
```

---

### Input

String with a valid chess move in algebraic notation

### Output

String describing the move (Upper case or Lower case is ok)

---

### Test Cases

```
fxg8=Q+  -> Pawn takes g8 promotes to Queen check
Bb7#     -> Bishop to b7 mate
0-0      -> short castle
0-0+     -> short castle check
0-0-0#   -> long castle mate
Rxg8     -> Rook takes g8
fxe6     -> Pawn takes e6
Ra8g8    -> Rook a8 to g8
Nb3#     -> Knight to b3 mate
a8=B     -> Pawn to a8 promotes to Bishop
Ra8xg8   -> Rook a8 takes g8
```

Comment: FWIW, I've seen variants of algebraic notation that use `:` for capture, e.g., `f:g8=Q`, and often with pawn captures, if it's unambiguous, just the two files are given: `fg=Q`.

Comment: Suggested test case: `Ra8xg8 -> Rook a8 takes g8` (?)

Comment: What is the meaning of `f`? I don't see it in the list of keywords? Is it a pawn?

Comment: @pajonk: F file pawn

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 206 bytes

Takes some inspiration from [Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264563/58563). But in the end, this is quite different.

```javascript
s=>[/O-O-/,/O-/,/.\d/g,/to (?=.*o)/,/x to/,..."=+#ORKBQN",/^.? /].map((r,j)=>s=s.replace(r,`long/short/ to $&// takes/ promotes to / check/ mate/ castle/Rook/King/Bishop/Queen/Knight/Pawn `.split`/`[j]))&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJfb4IwFMXf9ykaXAxM7H3QKHuoJryayOTVuVCxIoqU0G7z27OWP5Mh4wFC8@Pcc87lTL@oCPM4k@OUH1hxJIUgiy14Y28MNpQ3/H6AyAbJkbkk@IVb6uyGJAcbY2yQ0cDzV@5mbdjwgZcIdvhKM9PM7bNFFoIInLMsoSFTJ0HC0wjEiecSlAB6HoJ60gsTgLKcX7lkQp8DCk8svAC6UsnUCxUyYeBzfoFVrBTcWGlksPlkLIVVGkcnCW/0O0UBFlkSywCC7XlnWcOhKEKeCp4wnPDIPJoGmxqWhcpLzS4/UgPZ9KnD@dRpQMXp0Zqjr13ueIscshlp9ldPB0KR8ydS6bWK1ZVw9/NBPUtJVNn0J/t5mb@Lq9W0nJVl1g31kKO7cJvsN6KX7lVWFK931eB9PnyV/K5eNVQnfyyJze5oqyQ26@m9kW1UqaPbeFRVaGOhjf7jYb2ftFqufpqy5UlvOuoQt2uZa/32UqtdFT8)

#### Decoding examples

```
e4
 to e4
Pawn to e4
```

```
fxg8=Q+
fx to g8=Q+
f takes g8=Q+
f takes g8 promotes to Q+
f takes g8 promotes to Q check
f takes g8 promotes to Queen check
Pawn takes g8 promotes to Queen check
```

```
Ra8g8
R to a8 to g8
R a8 to g8
Rook a8 to g8
```

---

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 144 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Neil*

The same logic back-ported to Retina.

```
O-O-
long
O-
short
.\d
 to $&
-2`to 

x to
 takes
=
 promotes to 
\+
 check
#
 mate
O
 castle
R
Rook
K
King
B
Bishop
Q
Queen
N
Knight
^.? 
Pawn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU5BCsIwELzPKwJVEUo9qGgvRejFQ8HYnEWMdW1DayJtRH8fN4ednZ0dmBnJG6vDfHm8BZnJDIOzLXhPnRs9VpcHhHditkC2vjEBfnyzpnuaUEC8R/dynqbowiWFaDpqeiQQL@0JkgU9@YGgoJzrUaEynFCiNBzxRo36Q2RxQmVN23lcVweBs/5aEQJtoXSO56/NizpFed8n3E3GSSNkMoHiJztoF61MGaNyum8S6Lwo/w)

Comment: You can use ``-2`to `` to remove all occurrences of `to ` except the last.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 249 bytes

`-p` flag loops over input, modifies it with these two fat regex functions, and spits it back out.

```ruby
sub(/(^[a-g]?)?(.\d)?(x)?(?=.\d)|O(-O)+/){$4?%w(short long)[~/$//5]+' castle':"#{$1&&?P}#{' '+$2if$2} #{$3?:takes:'to'} "}
gsub(/[#+=B-R]/){|m|m[/\W/]?' '+%w(mate promotes\ to\  _ check)[m.ord%5]:%w(King Queen Rook Bishop Pawn).find{_1[m]}||:Knight}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LVDNaoNAGLzvUyxqoiJmSdK0IsiC19CaeOlhtUWT9YdEN-hKLGpfpJcc2r5THqW3bmoP3zB8zHzzMR-fVRO_fRPJPEnh5avhiWldf-om1pD2QiIzDbGOtVmwF9iKwc6N955merqB9E65w5OzVmes4vDIylQn70hBaBUaKtxFNT9S1ZbkTplPp3gzyJ0KVUNZ5ImyGKBYL7HNowOtbZUzdYDSANK_bCIbjmv6oUjoi74gKHhGIb6ZRVoRcQpPFSsYp3UAOQsgfIW7jO4OOilmrNpPVqEthOu8TOG2obSEPmMH6Obi0RPcROdSnyV5ue9e56QIh76312WeZnwYC_jv4XJ9TNrUcrYGcOMHGXimd5sRjZHKwBcSkLT0HviRJehTvJTBtk2EYZ3NQWQ5LvBjS6jGq78)

#### Partially ungolfed

````ruby
sub(/(^[a-g]?)?(.\d)?(x)?(?=.\d)/) { # Replace the part that says which piece moves where
 "#{
    $1&&?P                           # 'P' (Pawn) if group 1 is present
                                     #  (matches if input starts with /[a-g]x/ or /.\d/)
   }#{
    ' '+$2if$2                       # Group 2 with leading space if present
                                     #  (for Qb3e6 -> Queen b3 to e6 etc.)
   } #{
    $3?:takes:'to'                   # 'takes' if group 3 (x) is present, else 'to'
                                     #  (uses label notation :takes to save bytes)
   } "
}
sub(/O(-O)+/) { # Replace castling notation (original program checks for group 4)
   %w(short long)                    # ['short', 'long']
                 [
                  ~/$/               # Index of end of input (3-4 if O-O, 5-6 if O-O-O)
                      /5]            # Divide by 5 to get correct index for short vs long
    + ' castle'                      # Add the ' castle' part
}
gsub(/[#+=B-R]/) {|m|                # Match checkmate, check, promotes, pieces
   m[/\W/]?                          # If non-letter (checkmate, check, promote)
    ' '+                             # Leading space
    ['mate','promotes to ', nil, 'check'][m.ord%5]
                                     # Match the corresponding phrase by using mod 5
                                     # '#' -> 0, '=' -> 1, '+' -> 3

  :                                  # Otherwise (if letter)
    %w(King Queen Rook Bishop Pawn).find{_1[m]}
                                     # Find the piece that has that letter
    ||:Knight                        # If none found, it's a Knight (N can't match)
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>165</s> 146 bytes

```
ＦＳ≡ιx≔⊞ＯΦυ⊖Ｌκtakesυ-≔⟦⎇⊖Ｌυlong¦short⟧υ¿№βι≔⊞Ｏ⁺∨⁻υ⟦to⟧⟦Pawn⟧…⟦to⟧¬№υtakesιυ¿Σι⊞υ⁺⊟υι⊞υ§⪪”↶.⭆～»¤πη‽q∕¶lj,⊙↥⟲Qmº5σ¡²JＮ¤εlθw(LθΦG▶⁵@W｜]”¶⌕KQRBNO+#ι⪫υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJLTwIxEL7zK5p6mUa4G4kHxZjgAxbw5nqoy7DbUKabdqoY42/H2QXjxdN8zUy/x7RVY2MVrD8cNiEqmFKbecXRUQ3GqPThuGoUOKO@BpVNqPReX6rrlFxNUOTUzFuMlkOEO@cZI@ShusUq4g6JcQ2PSDU3sDXGDJVmu8WkBWUzPtGN/uhenjGSjZ/wD0Hu7/tAtZaamhBZm9cj0Ro3Nnu@VG6jYBIyMbwNlRP7//ksfE4wj/DkSIDYfdEc9KvpQGE/qIeTz8rjpAktHLtDNQt84s5/QfpU7phHoZc8nYVV3kGn3sl2071iIVy5n/4d/W1f85TWuIdV6x2DfpDVl7TIiFTSMoRtSTdOArclPZCrGy5JNscepTZYSXtnWQ5tDLvAmJT4FYcldXu@c7QWysXyZjY/P9O9vGzse1DICzPcB0d9HiVZxvIF9vXF1eL8MHr3Pw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ≡ι
```

Loop over the characters of the input string.

```
x≔⊞ＯΦυ⊖Ｌκtakesυ
```

For `x`, push `takes` to the result, but remove any bare letters (which will be the source file of a pawn capture).

```
-≔⟦⎇⊖Ｌυlong¦short⟧υ
```

For `-`, change `castle` to `short` but `short castle` to `long`. (The `castle` comes from the `O` below.)

```
¿№βι≔⊞Ｏ⁺∨⁻υ⟦to⟧⟦Pawn⟧…⟦to⟧¬№υtakesιυ
```

For other lower case letters, this might be the source or the destination file. Remove any existing `to` and add a new `to`, unless there is a `takes` in the string. Then push the file to the result.

```
¿Σι⊞υ⁺⊟υι
```

For digits, append the rank to the file.

```
⊞υ§⪪”↶.⭆～»¤πη‽q∕¶lj,⊙↥⟲Qmº5σ¡²JＮ¤εlθw(LθΦG▶⁵@W｜]”¶⌕KQRBNO+#ι
```

For other characters, push the piece name or notation to the result.

```
⪫υ
```

Join the collected words on spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>176</s> <s>172</s> 171 bytes

```
(([A-Z])(..)?|(.?))(x)?(.\d)
$2$#4$*P $3$#3$* to$5 $6
ox
akes
O-O-
long
O-
short
O
 castle
#
 mate
\+
 check
=
 promotes to 
K
King
Q
Queen
R
Rook
B
Bishop
N
Knight
P
Pawn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0/r4IwHEX3@ymatEOrgUF8ykKIrCTyZ1TfUPQnELQ1UCPD@@68up2c5J47kuuNXhYpz4fg9KtkGKr0T4apUnJWqQwvNwWxEXwrViUTkeCRWDFnxQ8TO9gZeqAJRVAEeFjTesLU2dGhALvqyT0IHOypHeGy9qqj64AE7DXap3U0@RRDjrz32wrVm8igRm3tgAxZ71svHJGbvu0cSpT6Y5blPrdxUq2RNXv@/UbtBe4z7VDr2OOxiTh0nGT/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(([A-Z])(..)?|(.?))(x)?(.\d)
$2$#4$*P $3$#3$* to$5 $6
```

Identify the piece or pawn being moved, whether there is a disambiguation square for the piece, and its destination.

```
ox
akes
```

Fix up the case of a capture.

```
O-O-
long
O-
short
O
 castle
```

Process castling.

```
#
 mate
\+
 check
=
 promotes to
```

Process other symbols.

```
K
King
Q
Queen
R
Rook
B
Bishop
N
Knight
P
Pawn
```

Expand the piece names.

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Saved 1 byte thanks to @ValueInk.

Comment: I think it's safe to use just `ox -> akes`.

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY27boMwGIX38xSW7Ep2IhhKm7IgFJYMSOEytkSqE/0BRGJH4AqGvjt1up2LzvlGcr3R64s8fK9Sfu2Dz5OSYajSXxmmSslFpbKZm1lBvAr@JjYlE5HgkdgwZ8U7EzvYBXqgCUVQBLhZ03qFqbOjQwF20ZO7ETjYXTtCs/VRR5cBCdhjtHfraPJXDDny3m8rVD9EBjVqawdkyHr/9cARuenbzqFEqWezrteljZNqi@z8wZ/sf36B2se4LrRDrWMvj@eIQ8dJ9vS@@wM)

Comment: @Arnauld D'oh, I knew there had to be a better way to do castling...

Comment: I believe you can use `(.\d)` instead of `(\w\w)` at the end of the first match to save a byte.

Comment: Shouldn't `xe4` give `Pawn takes e4`?

Comment: @Arnauld That should be invalid, it has to be either `dxe4` or `fxe4`.

Answer (score 0):

## C# .NET console app, 333 bytes

Assumes `using System; using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
string m=Regex.Replace(args[0],"(?<!x)[a-h](?!.*[x|a-h])","t${0}"),r=m[0]>96?"Pawn ":m[0]<49?(m.Length>4?"long":"short")+" castle ":"";foreach(var c in m){int i="-0RNBQKx+#=t".IndexOf(c);r+=",,,Rook ,Knight ,Bishop ,Queen ,King ,takes ,check,mate,promotes to ,to ".Split(',')[i+1];if(c!=m[0]&i<0)r+=c+(c<57?" ":"");}Console.Write(r);
```

### Commented

```
// add a 't' to the move string wherever "to" is needed
string m = Regex.Replace(args[0], "(?<!x)[a-h](?!.*[x|a-h])", "t${0}"), 

// start with 'Pawn' if the first character is a file, to or takes
    r = m[0] > 96 ? "Pawn " 

// decode castles now so we can ignore -,0 later
    : m[0]<49 ? (m.Length>4 ? "long" : "short") + " castle " : "";
    
// iterate through the move string 
foreach (var c in m) 
{
    // map each code to a word, with space where needed
    // 0,- map to empty string
    int i = "-0RNBQKx+#=t".IndexOf(c);
    r += ",,,Rook ,Knight ,Bishop ,Queen ,King ,takes ,check,mate,promotes to ,to ".Split(',')[i + 1];

    // anything that doesn't map is assumed to be a square reference and added to the result
    // except if it's the first character because if it's not x or t then it must be a file with no rank.
    // also add a space if it's a digit
    if (c != m[0] & i < 0)
        r += c + (c < 57 ? " " : "");
}

Console.Write(r);
```